# Draw line in gimp with macro

Tags: gimp, gimpfu

I have calculated a set of lines to be drawn onto the image I calculated the geometry from.
I was hoping for a macro recorder so I could just hack my geometry calculating program to spit out something similar.
All I need is example code that just draws a line from literal constants that I can just embed in a batch job. I can handle having to just cut and paste that into the script fu window. It's a fire once macro.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "macro recorder" in Gimp, you have to write scripts.

You can create a ["path"](https://www.gimp-forum.net/Thread-Paths-Basics) from a CSV using [this script](http://gimp-path-tools.sourceforge.net/tools.shtml#path-csv) (for straight lines, the coordinates of "tangents" are the same as those of their anchor)  and then use `Edit > Stroke path` (in "Line" mode) to render the lines.